# Unit testing an executable project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Maybe I am not thinking about this correctly.
I am starting my second project using unit tests.  My first project I rolled my own, for this project I am trying out Boost::test.

My question is, what are the proper procedures for unit testing projects that compile into executables?  It seems like everything I see out there is for libraries and dependencies.  I want my exe project to be unit tested, but I do not want a bunch of unit test functions floating around in the binary, nor do I want to do

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_func )
    {
    }
#endif
```

around all my tests.

I thought about creating a separate project for unit tests, but that does not really work for executable.. unless I want to do some fancy pre-build operation copying from my other project into the test project..

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: You should probably update your question to avoid misunderstandings - i do not seem to be the only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The project can be compiled as a library and this library linked, possibly statically, in two separate executables: the "project", which will be delivered, and the unit tests.

Now the problem seems to originate from your IDE, which one is it ? Does it allow to create two binaries for one project ?

Comment: I went with this solution, but make sure if you do this your compiler knows to link all the objects from library.  In visual studio you set Use Library Dependency Inputs in linker options, in gcc I believe the option is -z allextract or something

Answer (score 6):

i use ***cppunit*** to test my executables within an extra project which simply links to the *.obj files generated from the executables code. This way you don't have any test logic in the original code base and can write a seperate console or windows application for your tests.

Cheers
Holger

Comment: you can add the desired *.obj files to the linker input files like you would with a lib, at least in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The very idea is to create a seperate project where you test seperate *units* of code for the expected behaviour regardless of building debug or not (some issues don't even show up in debug builds due to code differences).
You build it as a binary and run to see if your changes didn't break anything - often it is even set up as a automatic post-build action.

If you want to test your application from the outside - there are probably some testing frameworks you can use, depending on the area/framework/etc. of the application... But Boost.Test and all the other unit testing frameworks are not intended for testing executables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I know unit testing works wonderfully with libraries, but I want to unit test my executable, so I need to actually define my main() function.  Something which was not a problem with my unit test solution, but is a problem with Boost::test :(

Comment: Providing a minimal main that inits the unit tests shouldn't be too much of a hassle. See here though for automatic initialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/initialization.html#utf.user-guide.initialization.auto-generation

Comment: If it helps, there here look like useful examples: http://github.com/jsankey/boost.test-examples/

Comment: yea I got boost::test 'working' ;p  Had to study the doc for a while to understand how to set everything up.  
My simple couple of tests work great if I do not define a main.  But I try using BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN and calling unit_test_main from my main function and it fails to link because the static lib defines main.  I am in the process of trying to rebuild the static lib, or even the dynamic lib now, but that still leaves me with an exe with a bunch of test definitions in it.

Comment: Ah, did you define `BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` during library build too?

Answer (score 2):

Unit-testing an executable can be a great idea - but realize that it's a whole different monster than unit-testing code.  Once you have an executable, there is no more C++ or Boost.  It's just a program.  You need to be able to run it and analyze/control your inputs in a different mechanism:

Input:

- arguments
- `stdin`
- environment variables (maybe)
- configuration files (maybe)

Output:

- return value
- `stdout`
- output files (maybe)

It's probably going to be easiest to run it inside a shell.  `bash` will work wonders in a Linux environment (pipe to/from files, run `sed`/`awk`/`grep` on the output to analyze correctness).  You could use Perl or Python and their own respective unit-testing frameworks, with the caveat that you have to wrap the invocation of your program in some other function: both languages support the notion of pipes from subprocesses, python with the `subprocess` module and Perl with its standard file-opening mechanism.

Whatever you do, you do *not* want to try to unit-test an entire executable from C++.

Comment: Well I do not really mean testing the built executable, I mean my project compiles as an exe, not a library.  Most unit testing frameworks are designed for libraries, hence the confusion and question.

Answer (score 1):

You can include necessary .cpp file from your unit test project and test it.

As I did:

Tests\GameServer\PVESettingsTest.cpp:

```
#include "../../sources/GameServer/PVESettings.cpp"
```

All works fine...

Comment: This method doubles compilation time. In your example `PVESettings.cpp` is compiled twice: for original project and for unit test. It might be insignificant for small projects, but will become a pain as the project grows.